# Fading out twitter bootstrap popover on different element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm using popover() function to, well, have popovers. I'm using it like this:

```
$(status).popover({
      trigger: 'click',
      placement: 'top',
      html: true,
      title: "<div style='color:black'>Details:</div>",
      content: $(statuses).html()})
```

And it works just like i want it to. Except one thing, right now when user clicks on specific element, he gets popover, and he needs to click that element again to get rid of it, which is actually the case. Is it possible to make it disappear after clicking ANYWHERE on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to set the `trigger` property to `focus`:

```
$(status).popover({
    trigger: 'focus',
    placement: 'top',
    html: true,
    title: "<div style='color:black'>Details:</div>",
    content: $(statuses).html()
});
```

This means that the popover is only active while the `status` element has focus in the browser, clicking anywhere else within the window will dismiss the popover.

Comment: does not display popover at all, perhaps I have the old version of bootstrap. hover and click work

Comment: That could be the issue. It definitely works with the latest bootstrap version. See the 'dismissable' demo here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers